# Having trouble with submit button function

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I write in the second Textarea field and click submit, it will only save the first textarea field instead of the second. I can't figure out how to connect the buttons to their appropriate textarea fields.

```
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class='hour'>9AM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class='input-group'>
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <p class='hour'>10AM</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class=" input-group-addon input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my code

```
$(".saveBtn").on('click',function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($("textarea").val() !== "") {    
      alert('saved');
      alert($("textarea").val());
      var textField = $('textarea').val();
      localStorage.setItem("textField", textField); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value from all the textarea. So loop through all the textarea and then check the value. If the value is not empty string then concat the value with a variable

```js
$(".saveBtn").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var textField = '';
  $('textarea').each(function(a, b) {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      textField += $(this).val();
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem("textField", textField);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class='hour'>9AM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class='input-group'>
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <p class='hour'>10AM</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class=" input-group-addon input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("textarea").val()`, it will take the first textarea's val.  This is different from `.text()` (on non-inputs) which combines all of them.

Demonstration:

```js
console.log($("textarea").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>x</textarea>
<textarea>y</textarea>
<button type='button'>click</button>
```

> how to connect the buttons to **their appropriate textarea**

In your case you need to find the *related* textarea, which you can do with some navigation / DOM traversal:

```
var textarea = $(this).closest(".time-block").find("textarea")
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(".saveBtn").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var txt = $(this).closest(".time-block").find("textarea");

  if (txt.val() !== "") {

    console.log('saved');
    console.log(txt.val());

    var value = txt.val();
    //localStorage.setItem("textField", value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class='hour'>9AM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class='input-group'>
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <p class='hour'>10AM</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" type='text' placeholder='placeholder' rows="2.9"></textarea>
        <div class="past"></div>
        <div class="present"></div>
        <div class="future"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class=" input-group-addon input-group-addon saveBtn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two text areas therefore, you have to loop in order to get values

```
$(".saveBtn").on('click',function (event){
event.preventDefault();
  let text_empty=1;
  $("textarea").each(function() {
      if($(this).val()==""){
         text_empty =0;
   }
 });
if (text_empty==0) {

 //alert('saved');
 //alert($("textarea").val());
    var no_of_text = 0;
   $("textarea").each(function(){
        var textField = $(this).val();

        localStorage.setItem("textField"+no_of_text, textField); 
   });
```

}
  });

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hackdawg/tsa7hk9L/10/) and try to work-around

```
 $(".saveBtn").on('click',function (){
 var textField="";
event.preventDefault();

if ($("textarea").val() != "") {

  $('textarea').each(function() {
if ($(this).val() != '') {
  textField += $(this).val();
}
  })
alert(textField)
localStorage.setItem("textField", textField);
```

Comment: You've kept the first if textarea != vall - which means if the first is empty but the 2nd is not empty, it won't save either instead of the requested just the 2nd.